# Angular: Accessing base element reference for elements with custom directives

Tags: angular

Given the following template:

```html
<input my-base-directive #someRef> {{someRef.value}}
```

How do I make `someRef` actually reference the `HTMLInputelement` rather than `my-base-directive`? I know i can use `exportAs`on the directive to make that accessible using the refs, but how do I explicitly *not* get the directive, and instead get the `<input>` element?

Stackblitz Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z6zvbz

Comment: What do you have in your directive? Can you share that code. `<input type="text" my-base-directive #someRef value="apple">{{ someRef.value }}` this will print 'apple'

Comment: Added link to a stackblitz

Comment: @yurzui I need to access it in the template, as it's created in a loop in my actual code, and i need access to a specific instance.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzqpvz?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @RasmusHansen can you share more about your specific requirement, maybe there is another way to solve it.

Comment: @yurzui: your stackblitz works perfectly. Can you explain this part `(input)="0"`.

Comment: This is required to perform change detection

Answer (score 0):

With this: `<input my-base-directive #someRef> {{someRef.value}}`

someRef will reference the DOM element the input box.

To get to the directive you need to use the 'exportAs' in the directive and use it like this: `<input my-base-directive #dir="mybasedir" #someRef [value]="name"> {{someRef.value}}`

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8dkrsn).

Comment: That is not working. I created a stackblitz that illustrates, however it look almost like yours.